# Timer and Timer Task

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have three timer task associated with a Timer and they are scheduled to run at different intervals. My requirement is if one of the timer task has completed the task, I need to cancel other timers associated with it. And also is it possible to send timer task name back to calling method?

```
package sample;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  private String name;
  MyTimerTask(String name){
    this.name =  name;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
      System.out.println("Timer task started at:"+new Date());
      completeTask();
      System.out.println("Timer task finished at:"+new Date());
  }

  private void completeTask() {
      try {
        System.out.println("In Timer Task");
          //assuming it takes 20 secs to complete the task
          Thread.sleep(20000);
          // Here i need to cancel other timer task and return name.
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
      TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask("T1");
      TimerTask timerTask2 = new MyTimerTask("T2");
      TimerTask timerTask3 = new MyTimerTask("T3");
      //running timer task as daemon thread
      Timer timer = new Timer(true);
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10*1000);

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, 0, 20*1000);
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask3, 0, 30*1000);

      //cancel after sometime
      try {
          Thread.sleep(120000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      timer.cancel();
      System.out.println("TimerTask cancelled");
      try {
          Thread.sleep(30000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: `time.cancel` cancels all the tasks.

Comment: In the above code, I wait for 120 secs and then do timer.cancel. But I need to cancel the timer if any of the scheduled task is completed. how to achieve that?

Comment: A Swing program should probably use `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland as long as there are no UI updates in the task, IMO, java.util.Timer is better.

Comment: @KDM I agree; I see the [tag:swing] tag is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constructor of the `MyTimerTask` to accept the `timer` as a parameter and assign it to a field. When the task is complete you can just do a `cancel` on the timer.

From the `TimerTask` you can't get the handle to the timer that scheduled it.

Comment: Sending the timer to MyTimerTask worked. now how will I know the timertask's name which cancelled the timer?

Comment: `this.name`? - You already have it. If the answer helped you - please accept it.

Comment: How will I know that timer has been cancelled from the main program?

Comment: There is no method in `Timer` that can tell you whether it is cancelled. You might be able to use `purge`, I am not sure. You can create a `Status` class having a boolean to hold the cancel status. Create a object of this class and share it among all your tasks. When the timer is cancelled, this can be updated. In this case, your Status class can also hold the name of the task that cancelled it and will be available in the main.